# Can't unmount /dev/sda2

Tags: umount

First I tried Gparted but couldn't unmount it
when I tried the terminal command `sudo umount /dev/sda2`

I got this message:

> umount: /: target is busy

.

lsblk -f /dev/sda gives this:

> NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE%
> MOUNTPOINT sda
> ├─sda1 │    vfat         5AF1-7D88
> └─sda2
> ext4         fc57d466-2433-4afc-88b8-6198c1fe1ce7  681.2G    20% /

Then I tried `sudo lsof /dev/sda2` I get lots of stuff part of it
is:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2    133200 32250945 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2     14624 32900921 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_umask.so
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2     18424 32901158 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_cap.so
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2     14448 32900895 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_permit.so
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2     14048 32900265 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_deny.so
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2     18720 32900267 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_env.so
sudo      17241             root  mem    REG    8,2    191504 32247723 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
lsof      17242             root  cwd    DIR    8,2      4096 37224450 /home/nada
lsof      17242             root  rtd    DIR    8,2      4096        2 /
lsof      17242             root  txt    REG    8,2    175744 32244418 /usr/bin/lsof
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2   5699248 32250545 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2    157224 32250050 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2     18848 32250026 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2    588488 32248600 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2   2029592 32247727 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2    163200 32252035 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2     27002 32904460 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
lsof      17242             root  mem    REG    8,2    191504 32247723 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
lsof      17243             root  cwd    DIR    8,2      4096 37224450 /home/nada
lsof      17243             root  rtd    DIR    8,2      4096        2 /
lsof      17243             root  txt    REG    8,2    175744 32244418 /usr/bin/lsof
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2   5699248 32250545 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2    157224 32250050 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2     18848 32250026 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.31.so
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2    588488 32248600 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0.9.0
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2   2029592 32247727 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2    163200 32252035 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lsof      17243             root  mem    REG    8,2    191504 32247723 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so
```

Comment: Is this your OS-partition? please add output of `lsblk -f /dev/sda` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1480263/edit) to your question.

Comment: Why do you want to unmount your root partition?

Comment: It's your OS partition, you can't unmount it. If you want to resize the partition, use your installer from USB and start Gparted from there.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from lsblk indicates that /dev/sda2 is mounted on `/` which is your root filesystem, containing your operating system.

You can't unmount filesystems that are in use.  The root filesystem will always be in use while the operating system is running.  The only way to unmount it is to shut the operating system down.

If you are trying to resize this or do some other operation that requires unmounting, you might want to try booting a live disk and doing the operation from there.

Comment: how can I boot a live disk n resize it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a root file that's why you can't unmount or resize it.
To resize it you need to run ubuntu from a usb out of this one.
To do this you need a usb and to download ubuntu on it
after this restart your laptop and go to the boot menu and choose to run the os on the usb
then choose to try ubuntu and it will open from the usb without installing it and of course the partition you want to resize will not be busy at this time so you can resize it or do whatever on it easily.